# Button themes in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I change the tint of the buttons within the android studio?

I see some properties when I select the button namely textColor, textColorHighlight, textColorHint and textColorLink

I'm expecting some built-in color themes without me creating custom styles, like standard green colored buttons, and blue secondary buttons.

[image]

Comment: You can set the background of a button to a colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change background tint color you can just use:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

or

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
```

and so on...
you can see other colors using autocomplete.